How to visualise 'simple' 3D vectors and points in QGIS
I am trying QGIS to visualize and analyse photo obtain with a drone.
I have a list of point where the photo have been taken (longitude, latitude, and z).
At each point, I would like to plot the drone vector: in which direction the drone nose is pointing at.
I cannot figure out how to do this in 3D.
I have extracted the metadata from the photo and created a GeoJSON with a point geometry and some field about the different angle (yaw, pitch and roll).
How can I load the file and put a vector on each point?

I had a look at LAS file, even if it seems overkill for my need, I did not figure out how to see a vector and how should be handle the angle.

